# ScrollView is messing up in iOS 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, scrollview

When I make and setup a scrollView in Xcode, It never works. It simply wont scroll and show my content! I have coded the backend of it but no go! I have been using this tutorial since iOS 4: [Devx Scrollview Tutorial](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/45113)

Now, I think it is broken in iOS 6 due to the new screen size on the new iPhone. Here is the backend code I have been using:

```
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 520);

//---set the content size of the scroll view---
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 520)];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
```

The scrollview sizes in Xcode are Width: 320, Height: 520.

What am I doing wrong? It is probably something stupid.

**Update:**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
      [self.overlay removeFromSuperview];
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:
     UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:
     UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

    tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                            action:@selector(didTapAnywhere:)];
    [self customizeAppearance];
     self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stone.png"]];

    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    scrollView.frame = ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds);

    //---set the content size of the scroll view---
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: What is specifically not happening that you are expecting?

Comment: Okay, but how much content do you have in the scrollview? If it's less than the height of the content size you have just set then it will not scroll. Usually, you set the content size's height to the last object's y-origin plus its height.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I showed you my code and the scrollview has the exact same values.

Comment: Set the scollview's content size's height to a higher value if you want it to scroll. (assuming the objects inside it take up more room than the frame height)

Comment: So pretty much, in the code, I say it higher and the scrollview's values?

Comment: Try it - if nothing happens that you expect, post some more code, because currently it's difficult to know exactly what you have done; for example, whether the scrollview has been added as a subview somewhere or not? Also whether there is anything in the scrollview or not.

Comment: This is the latest code and still no scroll:

Comment: I updated the code under the big bold UPDATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the frame size and content size to be the same. Where do you expect the scroll view to scroll to? You should set the `UIScrollView`'s `frame` to be where you want the viewport to be on the screen (probably `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds`), and the `contentSize` to be the total area you want the scroll to reach, it sounds like you want this to be 320x520.

I've written a simple example program. I created a new "single view" project and just put this in the `viewDidLoad` method of the main VC:

```
UIScrollView *sv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 424)];
UILabel *top = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 50)];
top.text = @"TOP";
top.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
top.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
top.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[sv addSubview:top];

UILabel *bottom = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 500, 280, 50)];
bottom.text = @"BOTTOM";
bottom.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
bottom.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
bottom.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[sv addSubview:bottom];

sv.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(280, 550);

[super.view addSubview:sv];
```

Comment: and do i set the scrollview's height to 520 if I want the content to be that high?

Comment: No, like I said, you set the scroll view's height to the area you want people to see at one time, and the content size to be the total content size.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)screenWasSwiped {

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
[scrollpage setScrollEnabled:YES];

[scrollpage setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1300)];

NSLog(@"you swiped the screen UP");

}else {
    [scrollpage setScrollEnabled:YES];

    [scrollpage setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 950)];

}
```

}

-(void)viewDidLoad {

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUP = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(screenWasSwiped)];
swipeUP.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeUP.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeUP];
```

}